# Lisp : (A (B C)), why 1 list and 1 atom?

Tags: list, syntax, lisp, parentheses

I'm learning **Lisp** and i don't understand some examples they give in a course for explaning **lists** and **atoms**.

I understand :

- (A B) : 1 list, 2 atoms
- (A B C) : 1 list, 3 atoms

I don't understand  this part:

- (A (B C)) : 1 list, 1 atom

After thinking a lot, I think that :

- A is the atom and (B C) is the list, but i don't really understand why....

  - why the first and the last parenthesis are not considered as being one list ?
  - why don't we count B and C as atoms here ?

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment on this weird thing :)

Comment: There's no getting around `A`, `B`, and `C` being atoms.

Comment: The accepted answer still misses a clarification to the initial confusion: lacking of the assumption that `A`, `B`, and `C` are atoms. Even with the `syntax` tag given in the OP's question, it is at least inaccurate that this is merely about the source syntax (usually Lisps are homoiconic so there are chances to have a mixture of different syntaxes from different evaluation phases) in the code. Alternatively, it may still work when `A`, `B` and `C` are not unevaluated symbols.

Comment: The key here is the notion of _redexes_ & _self-evaluating expressions_ in the evaluation algorithm. The dichotomy of the atoms and pairs in traditional Lisps is an imlementation of the technique to avoid non-list datum being reducible (not self-evaluating as expressions), but this is not necessarily true even among Lisps (e.g. Interlisp has self-evaluating data types neigher of atoms nor pairs). By extending proper list evaluation to pairs (e.g. in the Kernel language), pairs can still be significant, but atoms are not important as pairs besides the interest of the implementation details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say the answer is wrong. For consistency with the previous answers, it should have been:

- (A (B C)) : 2 lists, 3 atoms

Here's why: there are three atoms in total: `A B C`. There's a nested list: `(B C)` and an outer list: `(A (B C))`, totaling two lists.

It'd be correct to state that there's "1 list, 1 atom" if the question were "count the top-level elements *inside* the list" - but that's not consistent with the first two examples, which take into account all the atoms and lists shown, *including* the outer list.

Comment: I read it the same way Rainer seems to have: `(A B)` is one list of two atoms. `(A B C)` is one list of three atoms. `(A (B C))` is one list of one atom, and one non-atom (which happens to be a list of two atoms). Both seem to be internally consistent ways of reading what's given. Ideally, there would be further examples that would disambiguate what's actually meant.

Comment: Thks all for reponses, it's now clearer :) after reading all, i will remember that it depends on which level you looks on nested lists. So there is no one rigid response but it depends on what level you're looking.

Answer (score 4):

`(A (B C))` : 1 list, 1 atom, 1 list, 2 atoms

Answer (score 2):

As other people have indicated, this question is kind of confusing. But you can understand the concepts, even if the questions are confusing.

Let's take the first one:

```
(A B)
```

What is this? Well, it's a list, so it contains smaller things. Yay! How many elements are in it? No, really. Stop here and answer the question.

...

Two!

```
      (A B)
       ^ ^
    ___/ \___
   /         \
   |         |
element   element
  one       two
```

What are the elements? Two atoms: `A` and `B` . Note that, as the name "atom" suggests, they can't be broken down into further elements.

How about the second one?

```
(A B C)
```

It's also a list, but this one has three elements in it, again all atoms: `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Let's take the third one, which is more confusing:

```
(A (B C))
```

If you've been keeping track, this is also a list. How many elements does it have? This one is trickier.

...

Two! Two elements.

```
    (A (B C))
     ^ \___/
     /    \
    /      \
   /        \
   |        |
element  element
  one      two
```

The first element is `A` , and the second element is  `(B C)` . But wait, what are their types?

`A` is an atom, but `(B C)` is a list! So we recurse, and talk about `(B C)`. It's a list, with two elements: `B` and `C`. Both of these are atoms, so we're done.

So now you should understand lists a little better, even if the question from whatever book you're learning from doesn't quite make sense. But now it doesn't make sense because it's ill-defined, not because you don't understand the concepts.

Extra credit! List the types of the elements in this list, and if they're lists, keep going!

```
(A ((B C) D) (E F))
```

Comment: Thks for very clear explanation :) For this example, (A ((B C) D) (E F)), i will now think in several levels. For the bigger level, we have : 2 atoms and 2 lists. For a more precise level, we have 6 atoms and 4 lists. Don't know if is it right...?

Comment: Ok, so you think there the list comprises two atoms and two lists. So the list has four elements in it? What are they?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call A = Fred
(B C) = George
and  (A (B C)) = Ginny.

How many lists are Ginny?  Just one.   What does Ginny consist of?  One list, George, and one atom, Fred.

Hope that helps.

PS: Don't over-think it.

Comment: As [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16801674/1281433) pointed out, though, this interpretation isn't consistent with the other examples.  If the counts on the right are describing the elements of the top level list, then surely “(A B) : 1 list, 2 atoms” should have been “(A B) : 0 lists, 2 atoms,” since “(A B)” _contains_ no lists.

Answer (score 0):

Number of lists = number of paren pairs.  Number of atoms = number of everything else.  Lets apply it:

- (A B)     : 1 list, 2 atoms
- (A B C)   : 1 list, 3 atoms
- (A (B C)) : 2 lists, 3 atoms
- (((1)))   : 3 lists, 1 atom
- (A . B)   : 1 (improper) list, 2 atoms